# How to overlap these two widgets in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[Expected output of circle avatar and Container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewrVN.jpg)

[Current situation, the circle avatar is not on top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noQqj.png)

```
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:screenLayout(45, context),left: screenLayout(55, context)),
                child: Text('My Profile',
                 style: TextStyle(
                   fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                   color: color_mode.tertiaryColor,
                   letterSpacing: 1.3,
                   fontSize: screenLayout(43, context),
                   //add font later
                   //--//
                 ),
         ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          verticalSpace(40, context),
          Stack(
            children: [
              Positioned(
                child: Container(
                  height: getHeight(context)/3,
                  width: getWidth(context)/1.13,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.grey
                  ),
                ),
              ),
               Positioned(
                left: getWidth(context)/3.7,
                  top: getHeight(context)/4,
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    maxRadius: screenLayout(130, context),
                  ),
               ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
      );
```

Comment: Using the stack widget, you can overlap any two given widgets.

Comment: I used stack but got different output, not the one I expected

Comment: I figured it out. I wrapped the column in a stack, and added the circle avatar after the column and Inside the Stack Children. I'm leaving this here if this helps someone in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use stack in a bigger scope, maybe outside the column.